# Making (3) composite primary key less redundant

Tags: postgresql, database-design, primary-key, database-normalization, composite-primary-key

I have a table with a composite key (3) like this:

```
sub_product
 - product_id (PK FK)
 - product_type (PK FK)
 - size_id (PK FK)
 - quantity
```

quantity is dependent on all 3 keys.

Is reducing this to only 2 composite keys normalization?

Like this:

```
sub_product
 - id
 - product_id
 - product_type

inventory
 - sub_product_id (PK FK)
 - size_id (PK FK)
 - quantity
```

As soon as I add a column (like picture_id) that only depends on product_id and product_type normalization is mandatory. (Assume I would never add a picture_id column.)

Is doing this considered mandatory for normalization or is it rather up to personal preference and use case?

Answer (score 0):

It is not considered normalization. Normalization never calls for spurious pseudokeys.

Comment: Hey, "Spurious Pseudokeys" would be a great name for a garage band. Just saying.